# Number of characters in sql query result

Tags: java, sql, spring

I am using Spring 3.1.1 with Hibernate 4 and a MSSQL database. Finally, I have been able to query my database with joins in my table that returns the correct answers. Although, it seems that it does not return the entire strings of my messages, but cuts at 29/30 digits. Here is my query:

```
SQLQuery sql = this.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT event.id as eventid, CAST(event_type.type_name AS varchar) as eventtype, event.check_date, event.event_date, event.status, CAST(event_message.message AS varchar) as eventmessage " + 
            "FROM event_log event " +
            "LEFT JOIN event_type " + 
            "ON (event.event_type_id = event_type.id) " + 
            "LEFT JOIN event_message " +
            "ON (event.event_message_id = event_message.id) " + 
            "WHERE event.event_type_id = " + jobId + 
            "ORDER BY eventid");
```

The result can be:

```
4506 Database 2014-01-15 14:14:15.02 2014-01-15 14:14:15.02 false Database-connection cannot be
```

Where the columns are id, task_name, check_date, event_date, status and the message-string at the end. .

The result goes to a `ArrayList<Object[]>` where I read `row[0]` etc. to get the entities in the row. The string message gets cut after 29 digits, which is disturbing. Why does it cut the string and how can I fix this? In my database the string exists in it's full and is entitled 400 characters max.

*I know this is probably not the best way to query my database, but it will do for my application since it works.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `varchar` without a length.  *Never* do this!

Replace:

```
CAST(event_type.type_name AS varchar)
```

With something like:

```
CAST(event_type.type_name AS varchar(255))
```

In some contexts, the default length is 32.  In some it is 1.  In general, though, *always* specify the length.

EDIT:

Actually, you probably don't even need the `cast`.  Why not just have `event_type.type_name` in the `select` list?

Comment: Thank you, did the trick! I need to cast because I get "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9" if I don't. Another way is to use addScalar but I have not tried that, cast was the answer I found at first. if I could upvote your answer i would.